# Enable and disable styling rules

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, legend

I have a vector layer in QGIS. I have added a bunch of rule for this layer. This is the `QDockWidget` for layer in QGIS main window.

[image: rule]

So each of interstate, divided, secondary is different rule added using
`QgsRuleBasedRendererV2`.

All the rule have the check box where I can manually toggle the visibility of the layer. Is there any way I can toggle this using python?

I tried to use layer tree

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for child in root.children():
    print type(child), child.layerName(), child.children()
```

but `child.children` is returning empty list instead of those rules.

Type of Road Network is `qgis._core.QgsLayerTreeLayer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a property of the layer, not of the layer tree.

Get the layer, and modify its renderer's rules

```
# A list of the layers' rules
rules = layer.rendererV2().rootRule().children()
# Deactivate a rule (in this example the first rule [0])
rules[0].setCheckState(False)
# Synchronize the legend with the symbology
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```

Comment: I tried to do this but this silently disable the rule and the checkbox status does not changes

Comment: This is only a repainting issue. Fix added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works in QGIS 2.0.

For 3.0, you must invoke [setActive](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedLabeling_1_1Rule.html#aa79d92d7ec516f48f5a24a56091a72bb) on the rule

```py
rules = layer.render().rootRule().children()
rules[0].setActive(False)
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
```